# Place Tooltip in QuillJS

Tags: tooltip, quill

How do you place a Tooltip in QuillJS? I'm having trouble getting the tooltip to be placed at the specified bounds:

```js
const Tooltip = Quill.import('ui/tooltip')
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});

quill.setText('Hello\nWorld!');
let myBounds = quill.getBounds(2, 1);
let myTooltip = new Tooltip(quill, myBounds);
myTooltip.show();
```

The tooltip shows up outside the editor. I can't find specific API documentation on creating a tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

I realized I needed to utilize the **position** method inside Tooltip. Pass in a reference object, such as one from **getBounds**, and the tooltip will appear at the bounds:

```js
    const Tooltip = Quill.import('ui/tooltip');

    var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
          ['image', 'code-block']
        ]
      },
      placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
      theme: 'snow' 
    });

    quill.setText('Hello\nWorld!');
    let myBounds = quill.getBounds(10, 0);
    let myTooltip = new Tooltip(quill);

    document.querySelector("#editor-container").addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{
      myTooltip.show();
      myTooltip.position(myBounds);
    })
```

Comment: How can I set it to show where the cursor is?